# Calling openParentApplication: requires what kind of iOS background

Tags: ios, apple-watch

According to the documentation, when an Apple Watch extension makes the openParentApplication:reply: call to communicate with the containing iOS app, if the containing app is not already running, the phone launches the containing app in the background, and passes an app:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:userInfo:reply call to the app delegate.

For the release version of Apple Watch, is this working? I have found posting saying this feature had a bug in a beta releases, but no details about it every working correctly.

Assuming the bug is no more, does the iOS app need to have background modes set for this to be true? If so, what capability should be chosen? Apple's own Lister example does not have this set.

Currently for my project, if my watch app is running, and the iOS app is not, issuing this call does NOT work, and the call eventually times out.  I know the call must be quick, but how quick. It usually works if the iOS app is running before the Watch makes the call.

My watch app asks the phone for some text information, the phone retrieves this from core data, and replies to the watch. I thought there would be enough time for that.

Any hints or help?

Steve Sheets

Answer (score 0):

`openParentApplication` doesn't require enabling a background mode to work. Are you doing everything in a background task, as suggested in Apple's [WatchKit tips](https://developer.apple.com/watchkit/tips/)?

If you don't use a background task to request additional time, the OS will kill your app almost immediately. This is why you are only seeing it work when the app is active.

You can start a background task using the `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` method provided by `UIApplication`. The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/) can provide some additional details.

Comment: Thanks for the information regarding not requiring a background mode to work.  I had already add beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler to my code in order to request additional background time.  However, for some reason, the call to openParentApplication when the containing app is not opened, does not launch the containing app in the background. Thus thus the app:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:userInfo:reply: method is never called. If the containg app is in the foreground, everything works fine.  There must be something else I am doing wrong.